# Need to remove part of spannableString

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

I have SpannableString which is used in TextView. It contains decorated tags.
I need to remove 1 tag (part of String itself surrounded with Span) and remain unchanged another part of SpannableString.

That allows me to remove span only:

```
public void removeTagFromStatusLine(String tagToRemove)    {
        SpannableString originalString = new SpannableString(listOfTagsOnTop.getText());

        RoundedBackgroundSpan[] rsArr =originalString.getSpans(0,originalString.length(), RoundedBackgroundSpan.class);

        for (RoundedBackgroundSpan span:rsArr){

            String tagStr = (originalString.subSequence(originalString.getSpanStart(span), originalString.getSpanEnd(span))).toString();
            if (tagToRemove.equals(tagStr)) {
                originalString.removeSpan(span);
            }
        }
        listOfTagsOnTop.setText(originalString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am building my SpannableString from scratch after deleting some parts. I haven't found a way to modify it.